# MarkupExtension derived class name: Using a partial name to reference it later is valid. What's the point?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

Using VS 2019. I'm surprised the name of a markup extension can be abbreviated as visible in this code which compiles and runs correctly.

In assembly `CustMarkExt`, I define the markup extension type as `MyExtension`:

```
using System.Windows.Markup;
namespace CustMarkExt {
    public class MyExtension : MarkupExtension {
        public override object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
            return "42/42";
        }
    }
}
```

In assembly `TestMyExtension` I refer to it as `My` (instead of expected `MyExtension`):

```
<Window x:Class="TestMyExtension.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestMyExtension"
        xmlns:myex="clr-namespace:CustMarkExt;assembly=CustMarkExt"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{myex:My}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To run the code two references are to be added:

- add reference to `system.xaml` in the extension assembly
- add reference to the extension in the other assembly

So what doesn't that mean? It doesn't seems to be a bug.

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/markup-extensions-for-xaml-overview?view=netframework-4.8#defining-the-support-type-for-a-custom-markup-extension

Comment: @Clemens: Makes sense, but I wouldn't have been able to find it myself. If you write an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.